# Jacoco for Android Instrumentation Test using AndroidJunit

Tags: android, testing, junit, jacoco

I am facing an issue while creating an test report using jacoco for Android Instrumentation Test. I am using AndroidJUnit4 to create test cases.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Created the test cases and placed under default src/androidTest directory. Tested all the test cases executed properly.
2. Integrated jacoco, taken the reference from https://github.com/mgouline/android-samples/blob/master/jacoco/jacoco.gradle
3. When I try to generate the jacoco report I am getting an error on gradle console that **:app:testDebugUnitTestCoverage SKIPPED**  but no other warning or error.
4. Also when I write the test cases using jUnit and everything is working as expected. I able to see the reports generated in the build directory.
   **Note**: As these are unit test cases so I put them in src/test not in src/androidTest

Does anybody has idea how we can create reports using jacoco for test cases created using AndroidJunit4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the coverage path which you have given may be wrong -:
Give as below also print value of variables using prinln method of gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to get reports for just put the flag
debug 
{testCoverageEnabled = true}

All other stuff will be taken care by gradle. You can see the report under build/reports/coverage/buildType/

I hope it will save somebody else's effort